# Map a custom command so as to be able to execute it n times

Tags: key-bindings

I am using this mapping:

```
" Class: transform init arg to variable assignment
" <Esc> is input as Ctrl + v <Esc> and shows as ^[
nnoremap » :norm 0wiself.<Esc>w"byiwEDa = <Esc>"bp
```

to be able to transform, in Python,
a line taken from a Python Class **init**  args to variable assignment.

```
1  def __init__():
2      self,
3      arg_1: str,
4      arg_2: str = "default_value",
5      arg_3: str = "another_default_value",
6  ):
7      self.arg_1 = arg_1
8      self.arg_2 = arg_2
9      self.arg_3 = arg_3
```

I can yank the lines 3, 4 and 5, and paste them after line 6, and then use the custom mapping
to transform each line into the variable assignment:

`arg_1: str,` becomes `self.arg_1 = arg_1`

How can I adapt the mapping so that I could do
`3»` to transform all the lines at once instead of going over each line individually ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know, if you just enter a number before your mapping it almost works. That's because for, say, `3»` Vim will behind the scenes add `.,.+2` after the `:` that precedes `norm`. You'd just need to do a bit more tweaking to your command to get it right. But that command is starting to get a bit unwieldy already. So alternatively...

You can use a routine substitution. For example...

```
:s/\v^(\s*)([^:]+):.*/\1self.\2 = \2
```

If you put that in a mapping...

```
:nnoremap » :s/\v^(\s*)([^:]+):.*/\1self.\2 = \2<cr>
```

...then, based on the same mechanism described above, you can enter the number of lines first and that number of lines will be effected.

So `3»` will effect current line and following two.

Comment: That’s great, thank you very much. However, it highlights many lines or other terms. I tried adding `|nohl` and `|nohl<cr>` at the end of the mapping but without success. Any idea on how to prevent this ?

Comment: Sure. An easy way it to just add `<c-l>` (for Control-L) at the end of the mapping. This is the screen redraw command (`:h CTRL-L`).

Comment: Great. I also just have found another solution by adding <bar>:nohl<cr> at the end of the mapping. Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, or `\|:nohl<cr>`. Both yours and this one escape the bar (or pipe) character `|` which is required in mappings if you're trying to use it as a command separator.